# Using chai to mock http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

I'm testing a nodejs app written using express. For the unit testing I'm using chai and sinon. I have the following route in my API that I would like to test.

In my test, I'm simulating the get request with the following code:

```
 chai.request(app)
            .get('/downloads')
            .send({ wmauth: {
                    _identity: {
                        cn: "username",
                    }
                } })
            .end((err, res) => {
            res.status.should.be.equal(200);
            res.body.should.be.a('object');
            res.body.should.have.property('Items', []);

            AWS.restore('DynamoDB.DocumentClient');
            done();
```

However, I'm always getting the error "Cannot read property '_identity' of undefined". Because the object "wmauth" is not sent in the request, so it is undefined. I have tried to use the send method to try to include it in the request, but no luck. I guess I need to mock it somehow and send it into the request but have no idea how to do it. Could someone help me with this?
Below the method to test:

```
 app.get('/downloads', async (req, res) => {
    const created_by_cn = req.wmauth['_identity'].cn;
    if(!created_by_cn) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'Mandatory parameters: created_by_cn',
        });
    }
    try {
        const data = await downloadService.getDownloads(created_by_cn);
        return res.status(200).json(data);
    }
    catch(error){
        res.status(500).json({error: error.message});
    }
});
```

THanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to use `req.body` as in:

```
const created_by_cn = req.body.wmauth['_identity'].cn;
```

Hope can solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Since `chai-http` use `superagent`, so according to its [doc](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), you need to use `query()` in order to pass query parameter in `get` request:

```
chai.request(app)
            .get('/downloads')
            .query({ wmauth: {_identity: {cn: "username"}}})
            .end((err, res) => { ... });
```

Then in the `express` route you can find the parameters in `req.query`:

```
app.get('/downloads', function (req, res) {  
  const created_by_cn = req.query.wmauth._identity.cn;
  ...
})
```